# Is the use of serialization a serious issue?

Tags: java, security, serialization

I've created a class Message for a Chat program that contains all the information about a specific message. Instances of Message are sent back and forth between the server and the clients. I'm using serialization (ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutputStream) to exchange those messages.

I have no control over the process of serialization and deserialization. The biggest problem for me is if some attacker wants to send a really heavy message (say several gigabytes), I have no way to avoid it and I might get some serious memory problems. This could be used for deny of service and it is serious.

I took a look at a lot of different topics about serialization and its security issues but no one mentions how to avoid this trivial issue. I would like to be able to retrieve the data as a byte array using a buffer so that I can stop reading at any moment. But I couldn't find any way to do that with serialization. ***Question***: Is this how I should handle that?

Also any comments on the security issues of serialization is welcome. I've heard that you can inject malicious code in an instance of a serializable class but how can this be possible since the definition of the class must be the same on the client and on the server?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Depends on how serious you are about security.

Comment: Just use JSON? There's no way to prevent a hard DDOS, but using Java serialization does have a number of downsides.

Comment: It seems like your question isn't really about serialization.  If you're concerned about people sending large messages, you should document the maximum message size and enforce it in your client APIs and on the server that transmits the messages.

Comment: @chrylis It seems like JSON wouldn't solve my problem because I need to set a size limit to avoid receiving to large files. KevinKrumwiede: My question is how to do it on the server?

Comment: I agree with @KevinKrumwiede. Yes, serialization vulnerabilities are a serious issue, and could lead to remote code execution by an attacker. See https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Deserialization_of_untrusted_data - At the very least verify received data with an HMAC and a strong key before an deserialization process starts.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write a FilterInputStream (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html) to throw an exception if it reads more than X bytes of data from its underlying stream?

There’s a method that you can use to replace calls to readObject on this page:

https://www.contrastsecurity.com/security-influencers/java-serialization-vulnerability-threatens-millions-of-applications

```
/**
 * A method to replace the unsafe ObjectInputStream.readObject() method built into Java. This method
 * checks to be sure the classes referenced are safe, the number of objects is limited to something sane,
 * and the number of bytes is limited to a reasonable number. The returned Object is also cast to the
 * specified type.
 *
 * @param type Class representing the object type expected to be returned
 * @param safeClasses List of Classes allowed in serialized object being read
 * @param maxObjects long representing the maximum number of objects allowed inside the serialized object being read
 * @param maxBytes long representing the maximum number of bytes allowed to be read from the InputStream
 * @param in InputStream containing an untrusted serialized object
 * @return Object read from the stream (cast to the Class of the type parameter)
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws ClassNotFoundException
 */

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static  T safeReadObject(Class<?> type, List<Class<?>> safeClasses, long maxObjects, long maxBytes, InputStream in ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // create an input stream limited to a certain number of bytes
    InputStream lis = new FilterInputStream( in ) {
        private long len = 0;
        public int read() throws IOException {
            int val = super.read();
            if (val != -1) {
                len++;
                checkLength();
            }
            return val;
        }
        public int read(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            int val = super.read(b, off, len);
            if (val > 0) {
                len += val;
                checkLength();
            }
            return val;
        }
        private void checkLength() throws IOException {
            if (len > maxBytes) {
                throw new SecurityException("Security violation: attempt to deserialize too many bytes from stream. Limit is " + maxBytes);
            }
        }
    };
    // create an object input stream that checks classes and limits the number of objects to read
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( lis ) {
        private int objCount = 0;
        boolean b = enableResolveObject(true);
        protected Object resolveObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
            if ( objCount++ > maxObjects ) throw new SecurityException( "Security violation: attempt to deserialize too many objects from stream. Limit is " + maxObjects );
            Object object = super.resolveObject(obj);
            return object;
        }
        protected Class<?> resolveClass(ObjectStreamClass osc) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            Class<?> clazz = super.resolveClass(osc);
            if (
                clazz.isArray() ||
                clazz.equals(type) ||
                clazz.equals(String.class) ||
                Number.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz) ||
                safeClasses.contains(clazz)
            ) return clazz;
            throw new SecurityException("Security violation: attempt to deserialize unauthorized " + clazz);
        }
    };
    // use the protected ObjectInputStream to read object safely and cast to T
    return (T)ois.readObject();
}
```

Comment: But I'm using an ObjectInputStream so I can't count the bytes as I have to use the readObject method.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that I need to repeatedly receive messages. Calling that function everytime will repeatedly create new OIS which will cause a stream header error. I have tried to subclass FilterInputStream and ObjectInputStream to solve this problem but the thing is the bytes aren't counted at all. I can send arbitrary large messages. It simply doesn't work.